# Whats UCMA 3.0 Voicexml Browser default audio format?

Tags: audio, browser, voicexml, ucma

Currently, I am developing a ucma 3.0 vxml application. In the voicexml document , I use a record element to take the caller's recording, and then send the recording to an exteranl web server and save it to a wav file.

whats the format of the saved wav file, 8KHz/8-bit or 8KHz/16-bit or 16KHz/16-bit?
Can I set or change the audio format of the ucma vxml Browser to generate audio with different format?

Answer (score 1):

They supported audio formats for UCMA VoiceXML are:

- Raw (headerless) 8kHz 8-bit mono mu-law [PCM] single channel. (G.711) -- audio/basic (from [RFC1521])
- Raw (headerless) 8kHz 8 bit mono A-law [PCM] single channel. (G.711) -- audio/x-alaw-basic
- WAV (RIFF header) 8kHz 8-bit mono mu-law [PCM] single channel. -- audio/x-wav
- WAV (RIFF header) 8kHz 8-bit mono A-law [PCM] single channel. -- audio/x-wav

The part after the "--" is the mime type. You specify the mime type in the "type" attribute of the "record" element.

Comment: Thans, Kevein. Yes,thats the voicexml 2.0 specification required.Can get additional audio fomat from UCMA3.0, such as •WAV (RIFF header) 16kHz 16-bit mono A-law [PCM] single channel

Comment: Thans, Kevein. Yes,thats the voicexml 2.0 specification required. Can I get additional audio fomat from UCMA3.0, such as WAV (RIFF header) 16kHz 16-bit mono A-law [PCM] single channel ? thats to say I want to get 16Khz, 16-bit, mono pcm audio. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The audio formats supported are platform specific. But this format is quite common for many IVR platforms because that is about as good a quality as most telephone devices can handle.